# Cloudflare masking useragent?

Tags: cloudflare

On the target cloudflare website, I include an image that is generated in PHP from an external website; however, when I embed the image on the targeted cloudflare website, when the users view the image (e.g.: `myexternal.com/image.php?param=value`), I want to grab their useragent information so I can determine if they are using Firefox or Chrome. But whenever they load the image more than once,  a different value is generated sometimes. e.g.: on one request it says they use firefox, on another a little later it says chrome. Why is this?

And sometimes the param that is included in the image url, `myexternalwebsite.com/image.php?param=value` is empty, when I know 100% it is set.

**EDIT, EXTRA INFO:** I'm not trying to get IPs from the users, but I have noticed when testing that IPs are masked cloudflare IPs, and not actual IPs of the users.

Comment: Some bots intentionally change user agents and OS often. I am not sure if this is what you are experiencing.

Comment: @closetnoc The data I collect is from users, though.

Comment: Okay. I was just checking just in case you were not aware of bot behaviors. Otherwise, I have no clue and I am interested in seeing what answers there are.

Comment: In regards to the IP address, see CloudFlare's docs on how to [restore the original visitor IP to my server logs](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/sections/200038166-How-do-I-restore-original-visitor-IP-to-my-server-logs-). For logging user agents when images are served, disable the cache in your CloudFlare settings, or set a Page Rule specific to those images, so they're not cached by servers closer to your clients (which is what CDN's do).

Comment: Just adding a quick note that we're (CloudFlare) not going to do anything to modify or change user agents, and we're also not going to do anything to modify the structure of the URL.

Comment: the useragent header depends on the browser beeing used by you users. So unless you doing the request by you self you do not have any control over this header. Some browser and bot even change this header between two requests. If you do the requests in question by your self you may have a plugin installed that changes the headers. And theoretically you could have a worker running in cloudflare that does change this header, but you would know so I don't think cloudflare does change your headers